# Webpack relative css url() with file-loader / css-loader

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-file-loader

Im quite new to webpack/npm and i'm trying to get my head around how to work with css urls in other project dependancies.

**Folder structure**

```
src
  fonts/
  scss/
    app.scss
  js/
    app.js
  img/
  index.html
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var extractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var cleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var htmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'js/app.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        stats: 'errors-only',
        compress: true,
        open: true,
        port: 9000
    },
    module: {

        rules: [

            // ES6 -> ES5 transpiler

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            }, 

            // SCSS to CSS -> Autoprefix -> Load CSS

            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: extractPlugin.extract({
                    use: [
                        'css-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                            options: { 
                                plugins: (loader) => [require('autoprefixer')()]
                            }
                        },
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                })
            },

            // HTML Loader
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ['html-loader']
            },

            // Image Loader
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'img/',
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // Font Loader
            {
                test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                            name: '[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }


        ]

    }, 
    plugins: [
        new extractPlugin({filename: 'scss/app.css'}),
        new cleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new htmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'src/index.html' }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery', 'window.jQuery': 'jquery' })
    ]
};
```

I've successfully included lightGallery in my project like so:

**app.js**

```
import 'lightgallery';
```

**app.scss**

```
@import '~lightgallery/dist/css/lightgallery.css';
```

The light gallery stylesheet references fonts which i'm successfully loading into the `fonts/` using the webpack `file-loader`

My problem is that the built css file is trying to reference the fonts relative from the scss folder instead of my root.

ie: `http://localhost:9000/scss/img/loading.gif`

I need all assets linked to from css to resolve from my root dir

ie `http://localhost:9000/img/loading.gif`

Is there anyway i can configure my css-loader to prepend all url's with a `/` ?

Help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `file-loader` respects [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath), but because you've not set it, the resulting path will be a relative path. You can set the public path to `/`.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/app.js',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

This will affect other loaders and plugins as well, which handle any assets. This is generally what you want and therefore recommended, but if you'd like to change it only for specific files you can use the `publicPath` option on `file-loader`.

```
{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
        outputPath: 'img/',
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        publicPath: '/'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please review my post on file-loader github? https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader/issues/299

I added a test repo in my last comment.